# Parenting Windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I create two windows in my app class as follows:

```
var presentationWindow = new PresentationWindow();
var interactionWindow = new InteractionWindow();

MainWindow = presentationWindow;
MainWindow.Show();
interactionWindow.Owner = MainWindow;
interactionWindow.Show();
```

Another application uses ::ShowWindow to hide my application.

```
::ShowWindow(PresentationWindowHwnd, SW_HIDE);
```

This causes the presentation window to hide itself, but it does not hide the interaction window.

I have a number of solutions for making sure both windows hide, solving that is not a problem per say. I would like to know why interaction window is not hidden along with presentation window given that it's owner property is set to presentation window.

Windows 7 64/32bit
Visual Studio 2010
.NET 4.0

Comment: +1 i like this question. So here is my guess. Try changing the interaction window style to ToolWindow, and check if this has any effect. I would say, that just setting an owner window, does not add any functionality much. In fact in can't remember in the win api, a long long time ago using it, that you actually could set an owner window. So its merely just for positioning and modal behavior. If the Tool window minimizes this is additional logic, if not then i would say its logic you have to put in by yourself.

Comment: @dowhilefor: Tried making it a tool window, no difference.

Comment: @Cameron: I think I'm discovering one of those differences as we speak =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimize/Maximize/Close all propagate to the owned windows of a parent; Hide however does not.

There is nothing within the MSDN documentation that leads me to believe it should behave any other way.

Comment: You cannot set ownership prior to calling show or showdialog. WPF's Window wraps an HWND, but the native window is not created until either of show or showdialog is called. An exception is thrown if this is attempted.

Comment: @Nathanael After investigating this further, it appears that `Hide` does not propagate to owned windows. Minimize/Maximize/Close however all do. I can not seem to find any documentation to make me believe that `Hide` should be hiding the owned windows. Do you have something that hints to this?

Comment: I don't have anything that hints to it. I expected that it would and when it didn't I was curious if I had done something wrong or if it was simply unsupported.